# Updating UI inside a closure via self a bad practice?

Tags: swift, multithreading, closures, completionhandler

I'm fairly new to multithreaded programming and so far I've been updating my UI/views inside closures via `self.myview.setTitle, etc.`

Here's a sample code of how I'm updating my UI inside handlers/closures

```
SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in
        switch authStatus
        {
        case .authorized:
            self.recordButton.isEnabled = true
        case .denied:
            self.recordButton.isEnabled = false
            self.recordButton.setTitle("User denied access to speech recognition", for: .disabled)
        case .restricted:
            self.recordButton.isEnabled = false
            self.recordButton.setTitle("Speech recognition is disabled for this device", for: .disabled)
        case .notDetermined:
            self.recordButton.isEnabled = false
            self.recordButton.setTitle("Speech recognition has not yet been authorized", for: .disabled)
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

That's just a sample of what I've been doing but I do that for other tasks too like downloading a json data from a weather API and updating my UIs acordingly, etc.

Now I've heard that this is bad practice and I was hoping to know why. Also, what is the correct way of updating the UI inside a closure thread?

Answer (score 4):

It is not at all bad practice to update the UI inside a closure.

But it is *totally wrong and expressly forbidden* to update the UI on any thread but the main thread. And you do not know that whether your closure is called (and running) on the main thread. In general, there is no certainty or likelihood that a completion handler called *asynchronously* will be called on the main thread.

Therefore, you should either *prove* that this code *is* running on the main thread, or else make certain by deliberately *getting* onto the main thread before updating the UI.

Comment: Appreciate the info. I can't prove that the code is running on the main thread as I don't know. So is it a good idea in general to always, instead of using `self.someview.`, to call DispatchQueue to get the main thread and update the UI there?

Comment: It is well to be on the safe side, yes. That is precisely what my answer is telling you.

Comment: To put it another way: You seem to have misunderstood what the potential "bad practice" is in this situation. My answer attempts to straighten that out for you. It's not a syntactical thing but rather a threading thing.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. On a side note, this only applies to UI right? I mean, I can update any other non-view variables as is in background threads? For example I have an instance variable array and I'm fetching something from the web. I can then store the results in the array without having to get main thread and doing it there, right? Apologies for the newbie question but I'm still new to multithread programming practices.

Comment: There is no law about what thread you update an instance property on, but dangers do lurk here. The main thread is always safe because there is just one and it is serial. If you use another thread you need to know what you're doing or things can potentially go wrong in very mysterious ways.

Comment: Apple documentation on the subject: [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH1-SW1). Doing work on background threads is often useful, but you must take care not to create data races. The Dispatch and OperationQueue APIs provide some handy abstractions to make it easier to get things right.